# How to remove irrelevant languages for categories which are assigned to a sales channel?

Tags: shopware6

We set up a Shopware 6.4.16.0 site for Germany with the languages de_DE and en_GB.

Now we want to setup an American sales channel with only English content.

We selected only English as a language for that sales channel, [duplicated the category tree](https://github.com/iMi-digital/shopware6-category-duplicator) and assigned the new root category to the American sales channel.

Sales channel details look like this:

[image: Sale Channel Details]

Unfortunately, in the categories all languages are selectable, which is confusing:

[image: Category Overview]

1. Should the irrelevant languages be hidden or is this working as intended. I did not find any GitHub issue for this yet. Or is this intended?
2. Probably we need to extend the admin UI to determine which languages are relevant for a (sub)category (via the sales channel assignment of the root category) and hide the irrelevant languages? What is a good starting point for this?

Answer (score 1):

The language dropdown in your second screenshot in fact works as expected. The languages are globally.

In theory there are two different translations systems inside shopware:

1. Content translation:

Every entity that you can edit in the admin in different languages uses this translation mechanism. The values in the different languages are stored in the DB and the correct value will be read according to the language in the context. This translation system is used in the second screenshot for the categories.

2. UI translation:

This translation system is used for the "snippet" system in the storefront, where you provide translations for text snippets that are displayed in the storefront. This is what your first screenshot shows.

Both translation systems are only loosely coupled in a way that the content will be displayed with the same locale as the rest of the UI translations whereever content from the DB is displayed in the storefront.

Answer (score 1):

With the admin extension of a plugin you could override both of the corresponding components and restrict the criteria for fetching the available languages in the language switcher.

```js
const { Component } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;

Component.override('sw-language-switch', {
    props: {
        salesChannelIds: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => {
                return [];
            },
        },
    },

    computed: {
        languageCriteria() {
            if (this.salesChannelIds.length) {
                const criteria = this.$super('languageCriteria');
                criteria.addFilter(Criteria.equalsAny(
                    'salesChannels.id',
                    this.salesChannelIds
                ));

                return criteria;
            }

            return this.$super('languageCriteria');
        }
    }
});


Component.override('sw-category-detail', {
    template: `{% block sw_category_language_switch %}
        <sw-language-switch
            :key="rootCategory?.id"
            :sales-channel-ids="salesChannelIds"
            :save-changes-function="saveOnLanguageChange"
            :abort-change-function="abortOnLanguageChange"
            :disabled="landingPageId === 'create'"
            @on-change="onChangeLanguage"
        />
        {% endblock %}`,

    data() {
        return {
            rootCategoryId: null,
            rootCategory: null,
        };
    },

    computed: {
        salesChannelIds() {
            if (!this.rootCategory) {
                return [];
            }

            return this.rootCategory.navigationSalesChannels.map((salesChannel) => {
                return salesChannel.id;
            });
        }
    },

    watch: {
        category(category) {
            if (!category || !category.path) {
                this.rootCategoryId = null;

                return;
            }

            const parentIds = category.path.split('|');

            this.rootCategoryId = parentIds[1];
        },

        rootCategoryId(rootCategoryId) {
            if (!rootCategoryId) {
                this.rootCategory = null;

                return;
            }

            const criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.addAssociation('navigationSalesChannels');

            this.categoryRepository.get(rootCategoryId, Shopware.Context.api, criteria)
                .then((rootCategory) => {
                    this.rootCategory = rootCategory;
                });
        },
    },
});
```

You could still tweak this a little. For example when you click on a category in the tree that won't feature the currently selected language, you could automatically switch to the relevant language instead. For now this example just restricts the options in the dropdown on category-by-category basis.